# How to check if a XSLT transformation with powerShell has finished?

Tags: powershell, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I'm using windows powershell for XSLT transformations. This my example:

```
$aTransformation= New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$aTransformation.load( "transformation.xslt" )
$aTransformation.Transform( "input.xml", "output.html" )
```

Is there any posibility to check when the transformation has finished?
`.Transform` seems to be only a void method.
Target is to use a script for several transformations.

Comment: `Transform` is synchronous, the operation will have completed by the time it returns.

Comment: @Mathias so there is no return value available when the operation has completed?

Comment: Nope. It either throws an exception (indicating failure), or it returns (indicating success/completion). Use a [`try/catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2#catching-errors) to handle (or ignore) the failure case as appropriate

Comment: @Mathias
What means it returns (indicating success/completion)? Could that state be checked?

Comment: If your statement after the `Transform` call gets executed then the `Transform` call run successfully.

Comment: Sorry for that naive question but does the script waits till `$aTransformation.Transform( "input.xml", "output.html" )` has finished before it continues with a next command e.g. `$aTransformation200 = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;` ?

Comment: It is all procedural, sequential programming so the statement after a `Transform()` call is only executed if and once that `Transform()` is finished.